# url fragment issue with angularjs router and jquerys sizzle

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, angularjs, sizzle

I hope this questions hasn't been asked before, but I couldn't find any help anywhere.

I am working on an AngularJS app with jQuery included. There seems to be a problem with the fragment of the url when opening the website.

**Scenario:**

I open the website http://example.org/ and angulars router appends the fragment #/ to the url. Everything works fine so far, navigation etc.

but once I reload the page with any fragment (e.g. #/) left in the url, I get an

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[rel=/]
```

in the console. It was raised by sizzle, which jQuery depends on.
It seems like such a stupid error, but I just can't find a solution

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out to be a 3rd party jQuery plugin, which tried to resolve the url fragment after jQuerys' ready state.